# SQL Question Using Count and Top in the same Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of records (all_records) that contains a `recordID` and status (open/closed).  For example,

ID    Status

---

1     Closed

2     Closed

3     Closed

4     Closed

5     Open

I am trying to write a query to return the count of closed records of the 3 records with the highest ID.  So, with the above, it would return 2 since of the 3 records with the highest ID, two are closed.  I thought the below would work, but it is returning 4 not 2:

```sql
select 
  recordid,
  (select top 3 count(recordid) from all_records where status = 'Closed') as CNT 
from 
  all_records
```

Comment: and your database is??

Comment: Sorry, SQL Server

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will probably work in any ANSI SQL Database (SELECT/INSERT but not CREATE)

```sql
create table tu (id int, name varchar(20));

insert into tu values (1, 'Closed');
insert into tu values (2, 'Closed');
insert into tu values (3, 'Closed');
insert into tu values (4, 'Closed');
insert into tu values (5, 'Open');
insert into tu values (6, 'Open');

select max(id) maxId, count(name) count, name
from tu
group by name;
```

Result

| maxId | count | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 4 | Closed |
| 6 | 2 | Open |

**Update - Per OP comment** -- *" I need the count of closed records of the 3 records with the highest ID"*

Get top-3 closed records with highest IDs

```sql
select top 3 id
from tu
where name = 'closed'
group by id
order by id desc
```

Result

| maxId |  |
| --- | --- |
| 4 |  |
| 3 |  |
| 2 |  |

Get count of top-3 closed records with highest IDs. This can return either 0, 1, 2, or 3

```sql
SELECT count(*) allCount
FROM
  (select top 3 id
   from tu
   where name = 'closed'
   group by id
   order by id desc) T
```

Result

| maxId |
| --- |
| 3 |

Answer (score 0):

How about conditional sum? A CTE (you could use a subquery instead, if you want) "sorts" rows by `ID` in descending order - it (`rn`) is then used in the final `where` clause so that only the last 3 `ID`s are being used.

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select id, status,
  3      row_number() over (order by id desc) rn
  4     from test
  5    )
  6  select sum(case when status = 'Closed' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt
  7  from temp
  8  where rn <= 3;

       CNT
----------
         2

SQL>
```

Comment: I think using fetch/offset inside with clause would be more useful in case the table is too large.